# Parse XML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

i m trying to parse a xml file into html.
So i atm go with following

```
<script>
  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlDoc.open("GET","test",false);
  xmlDoc.send("");
</script>
```

Now i want to "echo" the request, how do i do that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") || new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlDoc.readyState = 4 && xmlDoc.status == 200)  // Success
    {
        document.write(xmlDoc.responseText);
    }
}
xmlDoc.open("GET","test",false);
xmlDoc.send("");
```

Comment: Hi and thanks first of all for that, as far i cant get it work. Still i see a blank page and responseText is still "" any idea?

Comment: In the above answer you'll need == on readyState but apart from that it's a winner.

Answer (score 0):

***Parse an XML String***

The following code fragment parses an XML string into an XML DOM object:

```
txt="<bookstore><book>";
txt=txt+"<title>Everyday Italian</title>";
txt=txt+"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>";
txt=txt+"<year>2005</year>";
txt=txt+"</book></bookstore>";

if (window.DOMParser)
{
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
```

---

***Parse an XML Document***

The following code fragment parses an XML document into an XML DOM object:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{ // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: Hi, if i go for that and use document.write(xmlDoc.responseText) i always get "undefined"

Comment: @FabianBoulegue - There is **no** `xmlDoc.responseText` in my code.

Comment: yeahr but without i dont get a blank page - if i just use your code

Comment: @FabianBoulegue - Is your input file a **valid XML** file with correct syntax?

Comment: Added the XML to my question.<br>
if i check the reponse with firebug i can see the hole xml text inside but it just does not get displayed ^^

Comment: @FabianBoulegue - Your question was how to parse, not how to do output, as we all believe you know `document.write`. So did my answer helped you? :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks maybe you wanna check out my other javascript - xml questions ;)!

Comment: @FabianBoulegue - You are welcome, but more then "Thank you" I would appreciate your acceptance (click on check mark below a number left next to my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could either alert('your data or text here') the data and display it in a popup, or select a div using any variety of methods and use .html(data) to insert your data.